# How to call a Perl function in Python

Tags: python, perl

I have a few functions written in a Perl module. I have to call these functions in Python and get the output.

I have seen the link
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Extending_with_Perl. I am not able to find the Perl module which they have imported in Python.

When I try to install pyperl in Linux, it is not able to find it.

I am able to run simple Perl script and get the output, but I am unable to call a function written in Perl and get the output.

Comment: which function do you need to access in perl?

Comment: how did you try to install it?

Comment: I have created my own .pm file and I need to access it

Comment: pyperl actualy seems to be not maintained and old, in the github page its mentioning python1.5 and its not been updated for 4 years. i'd personally go for popen

Comment: i tried to install pyperl using yum. But got message that there is no such module

Comment: Using popen I am able to run simple perl script and get the output. But I want to call a specific function and get output

Comment: i've tried a fresh installation from http://search.cpan.org/dist/pyperl/ but it fails on Ubuntu too... If it's just a single function, won't it be easier to find the equivalent in python?

Comment: you can install it from source then. i dont think it will be in repos because its not maintained. theres a readme file here with instructions https://github.com/gitpan/pyperl

Comment: sadly, the install came up with `error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1`. My guess is it's some version compatibility since my python/debian os is pretty updated and last commit was 4 years ago =( . I would love it to work too since i can dig up my perl scripts from eons ago and put into my python ones

Comment: @alvas not surprised personally i would avoid installing a lib that mentions python1.5 in the docs and its not maintained anymore.

Comment: `Inline::Python` works quite well for embedding Python in Perl, but the other way around seems to be impractical at the moment.

Comment: Whooo, blast from the past! I fear pyperl has gone too long without maintenance to still work on recent Python and Perl versions..

Comment: History lesson: ActiveState wrote pyperl over a decade ago for Zope Corporation (then still called Digital Creations) to allow Perl to be used as a scripting language in Zope, next to Python. Zope got popular enough to maintain the bridge.

Comment: Using `popen` does not preclude loading a module and running arbitrary code in it. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21216050/1600898) for details.

Answer (score 5):

Use `popen` to run the Perl interpreter and execute the desired code. When running Perl, include the `-m MODULE` switch to load the desired module(s) and `-e EXPRESSION` to execute the function you want. For example, this code runs a function in the `POSIX` module and obtains its (string) result:

```
>>> os.popen('''
... perl -mPOSIX -e "print POSIX::asctime(localtime)"
... ''').read()
'Sun Jan 19 12:14:50 2014\n'
```

If you need to transmit more involved data structures between Python and Perl, use an intermediate format well supported in both languages, such as JSON:

```
>>> import os, json
>>> json.load(os.popen('''
... perl -e '
...   use POSIX qw(localtime asctime);
...   use JSON qw(to_json);
...   my @localtime = localtime(time);
...   print to_json({localtime => \@localtime,
...                  asctime => asctime(@localtime)});
... '
... '''))
{u'localtime': [10, 32, 12, 19, 0, 114, 0, 18, 0],
 u'asctime': u'Sun Jan 19 12:32:10 2014\n'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Was doing something simliar today, using a module called `perlfunc.py` at http://www.boriel.com/files/perlfunc.py.

Tested on:

- Python 2.7.12
- perl 5, version 22, subversion 1 (v5.22.1) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi

Did tiny fine-tuning on perlfunc.py:

- `raise RuntimeError(a.communicate()[1])` (line 41)
- removed 'defined' from line 132

`very_old.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
sub hello($)
{
   my $d = shift;
   return "Hello, $d!";
}

1;
```

`reuse_very_old_perl_sub.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from perlfunc import perlfunc, perlreq, perl5lib

@perlfunc
@perlreq('very_old.pl')
def hello(somebody):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert(hello('python-visit-perl') == 'Hello, python-visit-perl!')
```

Comment: thank you, jwodder, for formatting the content: it looks much easier on the eyes now.

Comment: I'm the author of that little snippet.
Recently I updated it to make it compatible with python 2.7.x and python3.
Feel free to contact me to improve it. :)
It's on github now: https://github.com/boriel/perlfunc/

Answer (score 0):

From [Presenting PyPerler](https://www.infty.nl/presenting-pyperler.html) ([github](https://github.com/tkluck/pyperler)):

> I spent some spare time writing a Python -> Perl interface. The
>   existing solution [pyperl](https://metacpan.org/release/pyperl) was originally written for very old versions
>   of Python and doesn't compile anymore. In the mean time, writing C
>   extensions to Python has become much easier thanks to Cython. I
>   thought it made sense to start from scratch and wrote PyPerler. I
>   thankfully made use of the PyPerl's Perl code for wrapping a Python
>   object. On the Python side, everything is new.
>
> PyPerler gives you the power of CPAN, and your (legacy?) perl
>   packages, in Python. Using Perl stuff is as easy as:

```
>>> import pyperler; i = pyperler.Interpreter()
>>> # use a CPAN module
>>> Table = i.use('Text::Table')
>>> t = Table("Planet", "Radius\nkm", "Density\ng/cm^3")
>>> _ = t.load(
...    [ "Mercury", 2360, 3.7 ],
...    [ "Venus", 6110, 5.1 ],
...    [ "Earth", 6378, 5.52 ],
...    [ "Jupiter", 71030, 1.3 ],
... )
>>> for line in t.table(): print line
Planet  Radius Density
        km     g/cm^3 
Mercury  2360  3.7    
Venus    6110  5.1    
Earth    6378  5.52   
Jupiter 71030  1.3
```

If you install the Class::Inspector CPAN package, then PyPerler will even get you introspection for use in IPython.